# Parse microsoft xml schema in php

Tags: xml, schema

Im working with a web service that replaying data in microsoft xml schema structure like a part of those that i writing there.

```
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:isdataset="true" msdata:maindatatable="xml" msdata:usecurrentlocale="true"><xs:complextype><xs  :choice minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="xml"><xs:complextype><xs:sequence><xs:elemen  t name="order" msdata:autoincrement="true" msdata:autoincrementseed="1" type="xs:decimal" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="SenderMobileNo" type="xs:string" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="OperatorRowId" type="xs:string" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="SendTime" type="xs:dateTime" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="m_RecieveTime" type="xs:dateTime" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="m_RecieveToAhraTime" type="xs:dateTime" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="Body" type="xs:string" minoccurs="0"><xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:string" minoccurs="0"></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:element></xs:sequence></xs:complextype></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complextype></xs:element></xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <documentelement xmlns="">
    <xml diffgr:id="xml13" msdata:roworder="0"><order>1</order><sendermobileno>09350000700</sendermobileno><operatorrowid>104997</operatorrowid><sendtime>2014-02-03T22:35:33+03:30</sendtime><m_recievetime>2014-02-03T22:35:33+03:30</m_recievetime><m_recievetoahratime>2014-02-03T22:35:33+03:30</m_recievetoahratime>THE MAIN TEXT 1111<linenumber>30000881</linenumber></xml>
    <xml diffgr:id="xml14" msdata:roworder="1"><order>2</order><sendermobileno>09350000700</sendermobileno><operatorrowid>104998</operatorrowid><sendtime>2014-02-03T23:41:32+03:30</sendtime><m_recievetime>2014-02-03T23:41:32+03:30</m_recievetime><m_recievetoahratime>2014-02-03T23:41:32+03:30</m_recievetoahratime>THE MAIN TEXT 2222<linenumber>30000881</linenumber></xml>
</documentelement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Now i need to parse it in php and use all of those given data in an structure like an array!

Note: I'm sorry about my bad English writing.

Comment: My question is how to read it!How to save it to DB! And how to use those data!

Comment: I need to convert it to array!

Comment: Yes!! Vrey Very much!But it does not work!